# How can I remove the straight line from the image?

Tags: image-processing

I am using Matlab program.

How can I remove the straight line from the black and white image?

The sample image is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the results already,

This is my code.

```
RGBImg = imread('test.png');
    grayImg = rgb2gray(RGBImg);
Img = im2bw(grayImg);

Img = ~Img;
bwImgs = bwareaopen(Img,70);

se90 = strel('line', 2, 90);
se0 = strel('line', 2, 0);
borderImgs = double(imdilate(bwImgs, [se90 se0]));
%figure; imshow(borderImgs);

%remove border
%***************************************************************
[row col dim] = size(RGBImg);
rmBorderImgs = RGBImg;


for r=1:row
    for c=1:col
        if borderImgs(r,c) == 1
            rmBorderImgs(r,c,1) = 255;
            rmBorderImgs(r,c,2) = 255;
            rmBorderImgs(r,c,3) = 255;
        end
    end
end
```

This is result image;

[image]

**Do you have a better idea about this?**

could you suggestion me?